# PHP prepared statement: Why is this throwing a fatal error?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

Have no idea whats going wrong here. Keeps throwing...

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object

...every time it gets to the `$select = $dbcon->prepare('SELECT * FROM tester1');`part. Can somebody shed some light as to what I'm doing wrong?

```
function selectall()            //returns array $client[][]. first brace indicates the row. second indicates the field
  {
  global $dbcon;

  $select = $dbcon->prepare('SELECT * FROM tester1');
  if ($select->execute(array()))
    {
    $query = $select->fetchall();

    $i = 0;

    foreach ($query as $row)
      {
      $client[$i][0] = $row['id'];
      $client[$i][1] = $row['name'];
      $client[$i][2] = $row['age'];
      $i++;
      }
    }
  return $client;
  } 
$client = selectall();
echo $client[0][0];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The obvious answer is that `$dbcon` hasn't been initialized at all or is initialized after this function is called.

What code is initializing `$dbcon`? Where and when is it run? You also realize that you will need to initialize it on *every* invocation of a script that accesses the database? The last is just to make sure that you understand what the `global` scope in PHP is. It means scoped to that single request. The term `global` is a little misleading.

Comment: If you read the errors, they tend to tell you EXACTLY what the problem is.

Comment: Um. Read the error. Didn't make sense. I put it in the original post

Answer (score 0):

make sure you define `$dbcon` properly. If you are using mysqli, see how the connection is setup in the [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).  you  can also pass the connection object to the function

```
function selectall($dbcon){
   ....
}
```